# Can TFS 2010 be used to store and version non-code files?

Tags: tfs

We are using internally TFS 2010 as source control repository for our .NET Projects.

Some colleagues from other departments are asking us if we can provide them a system to version their files (binary or other files) not "source code" related and I was thinking if is possible to use and configure TFS 2010 to help them.

Keep in mind they don't want to install Visual Studio and for this reason a web interface is need or a GUI for command line TFS commands.

Do you think is feasible and effective?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We put our documents in SharePoint.  SharePoint has a version history, and people can access it with office and a web browser, without having to have visual studio.

For those who do use TFS 2010 in your project/company, there is a TFS 2010 plugin for MOSS 2007 (and eventually will be for SP2010).

Comment: I am trying to implement versioning in SharePoint 2010 as suggested. Probably it is enough for them with the benefit that they don't need to install anything on their PC. Thank you.

Comment: In my organization, the SharePoint servers and environment have not been stable and trustworthy places to keep documentation over the last 5+ years.   Here in 2017, we are still on SharePoint 2010.  Even then, many folders and documents and privileges were not handled well (i.e., people lost access to nearly all their historical documents that lived only in SharePoint) during the migration from SharePoint 2007 to 2010.  So, before you trust important documents to SharePoint, make sure your organization has a reliable governance and administration structure for the SharePoint environment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da) to check-in and out files from Windows Explorer.  Be sure to install the Windows Shell Extensions.  Unfortunately, I think you will still need to install Team Explorer as well for the Power Tools to work.

We put DLL's, documentation, and zips into source control when we need to.  There isn't any technical reason why you can't source control binary file types.

Answer (score 1):

> Some colleagues from other departments
> are asking us if we can provide them a
> system to version their files
>
> Keep in mind they don't want to
> install Visual Studio and for this
> reason a web interface is need or a
> GUI for command line TFS commands.

I'm assuming from this, that these are not IT people.

As alex mentioned, they would have to install Team Explorer, which is not too friendly for non-IT people.  You'd probably be faced with creating a more friendly UI.

At that point, I would strongly suggest that you *not* use TFS for this.  Instead, look into using SharePoint, which also supports versioning, but without all of the "release management" overhead (like changesets and labeling) that these users would most likely never take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

Sure we use it for other types of files like word docs and excel spreadsheets. But, they will need to use Team Explorer and they mush have a Client Access License to change the files.

Comment: And you can use TFS Server Power Tools to get Windows Explorer integration.

Answer (score 0):

TFS web access will do this for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892990(VS.90).aspx

We use a CMMI template and use this for version control of our associated development documentation.

Comment: I don't think you can use the web access to check in and check out can you? I thought it was only for browsing and reading.

Comment: I tried and I confirm that it works as Alex said, only reading and browsing.

Comment: you can add version controlled documents, in a sharepoint like fashion. ie check out and check in, its on the drop down list at the side of the document. or atleast on my projects we can. its possible that it needs some initial configuration on the project. which i think is what the OP is looking for.